# How to remove the duplicates objects from Hashmap in javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have a hashmap in which I would like to remove the duplicate objects with the same userId. Can anyone tell me how to do it?
I have tried with lodash uniq but it is meant for arrays. Can anyone help me please?

```
   {
     1545300600396:{name: "Mani", uniqueId: 1545300600396, userId: "-LUA49YctCb5Nf0H4Oub"},
     1545300600397:{name: "Sundar", uniqueId: 1545300600397, userId: "-LUA4TtvB4Oaaas9yiZ_"},
     1545300686269:{name: "Vetri vela", uniqueId: 1545300686269, userId: "-LUA4pFE6s_GAZ2F-ywP"},
     1545300686270:{name: "Sabarish", uniqueId: 1545300686270, userId: "-LUA57BpO-orsWfiCL__"},
     1545391149707:{name: "Mani", uniqueId: 1545391149707, userId: "-LUA49YctCb5Nf0H4Oub"}
   }
```

Expected Output:

```
   {
     1545300600396:{name: "Mani", uniqueId: 1545300600396, userId: "-LUA49YctCb5Nf0H4Oub"},
     1545300600397:{name: "Sundar", uniqueId: 1545300600397, userId: "-LUA4TtvB4Oaaas9yiZ_"},
     1545300686269:{name: "Vetri vela", uniqueId: 1545300686269, userId: "-LUA4pFE6s_GAZ2F-ywP"},
     1545300686270:{name: "Sabarish", uniqueId: 1545300686270, userId: "-LUA57BpO-orsWfiCL__"}
  }
```

Comment: HashMap or something ?

Comment: @MohammadUmair Hashmap

Comment: You have two options. Iterate through all the keys starting from next,for every current key, and compare the userId and delete that object. or use userId as the key of the hash and drop the duplicate during collision.

Comment: In javascript, when you refer to a hashmap it would be a `Map`, but you present an object literal. Please provide example with desired output.

Comment: @trincot i have updated the question can you pls have a look

Comment: Why do you need the uniqueId at all if you could just use the userId as map key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could iterate your object properties and `delete` the duplicates based on a temporary `Set`:

```js
const data = {1545300600396:{name: "Mani", uniqueId: 1545300600396, userId: "-LUA49YctCb5Nf0H4Oub"}, 1545300600397:{name: "Sundar", uniqueId: 1545300600397, userId: "-LUA4TtvB4Oaaas9yiZ_"}, 1545300686269:{name: "Vetri vela", uniqueId: 1545300686269, userId: "-LUA4pFE6s_GAZ2F-ywP"}, 1545300686270:{name: "Sabarish", uniqueId: 1545300686270, userId: "-LUA57BpO-orsWfiCL__"},1545391149707:{name: "Mani", uniqueId: 1545391149707, userId: "-LUA49YctCb5Nf0H4Oub"}};

const set = new Set;
for (const id in data) {
    if (set.has(data[id].userId)) delete data[id];
    else set.add(data[id].userId);
}

console.log(data);
```